# custom showing with Maronette

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

Hi I want to implement my fancy fade in effect on each element in composite view. The code is working, but the trigger method onDomRefresh" is not correct.

How can I replace "onDomRefresh" so as it can actually work. It is triggered, but to late,so no effect fadein is visible. Seems like "onRender" and "onShow" is not working too.

```
 # controllers triggering "show"

 conferenceRegion: (conferences) ->
   conferenceView = @getConferenceView conferences
   @layout.conferenceRegion.show conferenceView


#list_view executing "show"

 class List.ConferenceSingle extends App.Views.ItemView
   template: "conference/list/_conference_single"
   className: 'conference_li'
   tagName: "li"

 class List.Conference extends App.Views.CompositeView
    template: "conference/list/_conference"
    itemView: List.ConferenceSingle
    itemViewContainer: "ul"
    onDomRefresh: ->
       @childElementsFadeIn()

    childElementsFadeIn: ->
      duration = 500;
      @$el.find('.conference_li').each (index) ->
        $(this).delay((index+1) * duration).fadeIn(500)
```

Interesting think is when I am calling function "onRender" without delay, the effect is working. Wy can not I do it with a delay()?

```
 childElementsFadeIn: ->
      duration = 500;
      @$el.find('.conference_li').each (index) ->
        $(this).fadeIn(1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `onDomRefresh` should work.

The reason you can't see the effect is the elements are already displayed, so there is nothing can be "fadeIn".

If that's correct, it can be fixed by simply add a `hide()` method before fancy effect.

```
onDomRefresh: ->
  @$el.hide()
  @childElementsFadeIn()
```